# the error says variable X is not given, but the variable x is declared before

Tags: sas

I get an error when trying to plot this in SAS, the error says variable X is not given, but the variable x is declared before.

Here is my code:

```
data prg7_5;
do a=1 to 3;
input x@@;
output
end;
cards;
7028 1764 600 7228 2036 744 
7228 2130 804 8448 2536 844
8567 2436 912 9061 2436 1128 
9167 3108 1320 9167 3108 1464 
10032 3108 1608 10051 3208 1896
;
run;
goptions hsize=5 vsize=4 ftext='宋体';
footnote 'the time ';
symbol1 interpol=boxt00 width=1.8 bwidth=5 co=red;
axis1 label  =('temperature(C)')
    value=('190' ' 220 ' '260')
    minor=none
    offset=(10,10);
axis2 label =(angle=90'the time')
    offset=(0,0);
proc gplot data= prg7_5;
    plot x*a/haxis=axis1
        vaxis=axis2;
run;
```

here is the run log:
[image]
Can you show me the correct way to do it? Please help

Comment: When debugging fix the first error because later errors could be side effects of the earlier failure, as in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a  semicolon after output. Your dataset will be empty and you have following error.

```
  ERROR 117-185: There was 1 unclosed DO block.

 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.PRG7_5 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped 
there were 0 observations and 2 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.PRG7_5 was not replaced because this step was stopped.
```

change code with semicolon at output as shown below

```
 do a=1 to 3;
  input x@@;
  output;
 end;
```